# Which is faster: reading and modifying object or serialized string replace via regex

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm just curius about this, but if I were to have an object

```
var my_obj = {
    one: "one",
    two: "two",
    three: "three"
    n: "254635"
};
```

is it faster to read it and modify it like an object? Or to make it a string:

```
JSON.stringify(my_obj);
```

and then read it with a regex?

I know that JSON string occupy less space, what I'm asking is which is faster to modify AND read?

And by this I dont mean to say that I have to do both. The question is simlar to saying "If you read an object, is it faster than reading a json string?", and the same for the modification of that string/object.

ALSO, which one uses less resources?

Comment: Manipulating it as an object is going to be faster in almost all cases, *much* faster in many cases, and clearly less weird and fragile in absolutely all cases.

Comment: *"to modify AND read"* - You can't modify a string, you can only create a new string (as a result of `.replace()`and/or other string methods and concatenation) and throw away the old one.

Comment: @nnnnnn but you can set i to itself

Comment: @nnnnnn By that I mean, if you were to read an object, is it faster than the json string? If you modify an object, is it faster than a json string?

Comment: I don't think regex can parse JSON properly. Don't do that.

Comment: If you assign the result of string manipulation back to the same variable the original string should get garbage collected, but that doesn't happen instantly, and you did ask about use of resources... As Pointy said, manipulating an object should be faster, and it is certainly a lot simpler and therefore less likely to go wrong. If you're that worried about it, do your own [performance test](http://jsperf.com).